# What is the type of this IP?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I caught an IP address on Facebook but this is not basic IP. Do you know what it means and what is this type of IP ?

It's look like an MAC address

Thank for your help, it's a bit important

[link of the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pxpt.png)

Comment: This site is for programming questions, which this is not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an IP version 6 (IPV6).

Please refer here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6
- http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv6-parameters/ipv6-parameters.xhtml

Comment: exactly ! he is geolocalized in USA, he using a VPN. thank you ;)